# OSGI bundle possibility

Tags: java, dependencies, osgi, startup, osgi-bundle

I have two bundles A and B, with start-up for **A** as 4 and **B** as 5.

There is a library in bundle A, Which is in-need of class in bundle B.

Bundle B is dependent of Bundle A, [Bundle B gets started after Bundle A being started]
So I cannot make bundle B to be dependent for A, It becomes tightly coupled, So Is there a way I can use the class in bundle B in Bundle A without being added as dependent bundle.

Even when I import package of Bundle B in Bundle A, It shows as tightly coupled.

Guys give me some solution...

Answer (score 0):

It's time to refactor your code. Based on the information you provided, you should at least creating bundle C that contains the classes that are used from bundle A and bundle B.

It often happens that a bundle is splitted into multiple bundles as it turns out that the logic in that bundle should be implemented in multiple bundles.

The API and implementation should always be separated to different bundles. I guess both your bundles contain API and implementation as well.

If you need the circle wirings due to the reason that you use Factories, refactor your code in the way that you separate the API to different bundles and based on the API, the implementation bundle offers OSGi services.

Comment: Its not an API / Implementation bundle, that bundle has a bean classes which is specific to a business logic... So am not able to move that class to bundle C, If I do that, Then I need to have number of third bundle based on the use case.